# Facebook v4.0 SDK with Codeigniter and Composer

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, composer-php

I am updating my app to use the Facebook v4 php sdk and am having issues installing it via composer in codeigniter.

I have been using composer with codeigniter without an issue for some time and am loading my autoload file in my index.php.

When running the code I keep getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found in /var/www/dev/application/controllers/playground.php on line 12
```

Here is my Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

class Playground extends MY_Controller {
    public function index() {
       FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('-removed-','-removed-');
    }
 }
```

I have no idea why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and it was my own mistake

The facebook documentation correctly tells you to use the following

"facebook/php-sdk-v4": "4.0.*"

The latest composer package on packagist leads you to download the following

"facebook/php-sdk-v4": "4.1.*@dev"

Comment: Had you solved the issues of facebook login with code ignitor. If already done. Please explain the process.